# Is the only use of function pointers to implement callbacks?

Tags: c, function-pointers, use-case

I have come across the fact that function pointers can be used to implement callbacks. Is there any other usage of function pointers? Is there any other situation that function pointers proved to be useful?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but I can only select one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about sorting? Pass in a function pointer to compare any two elements.

How about filtering? Pass in a function pointer to decide whether an input element should be contained in the output of a filter.

How about transformations? Pass in a function pointer to convert an input element to an output element.

These are all collection-based uses, but they're very useful. (The broad equivalent of function pointers in .NET is delegates, and they're the basis of LINQ, which allows very simple querying, transformations, grouping etc.)

Anywhere you want to be able to abstract out the idea of "a single piece of behaviour", writing a generic function which doesn't need to know the details of that behaviour, a function pointer could be useful.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but I'd refer to all of those cases as "callbacks", for the simple reason that in C it's slightly unusual for a function to call any kind of user-supplied code, so pretty much anything of that sort I'd refer to as a "callback" in C. Possibly what the questioner is calling "callbacks" is what I'd normally call "async callbacks", or "registered callbacks/listeners", and thinking about it, when using Java I certainly don't refer to every call on a user-supplied object as a "callback"...

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Jon wrote, function pointers in C can be used to implement OO programming style (e.g. polymorphism).

Answer (score 2):

Function pointers (or their typed and more advanced equivalents) are a helpful feature when implementing inversion of control related patterns. All examples mentioned are applications of IoC principle (the sorting algorithm does not control the used predicate, the call to an object method is delayed until run-time etc)

Regards,

Paul

Comment: I am sure that it would be useful for you to elaborate on *"typed and more advanced equivalents"* - rather too enigmatic perhaps..

Comment: Well, elaborating on that could fill entire books - therefore a few "buzzwords" should do the job, I believe...

Comment: Maybe, but I have no idea what you mean, so perhaps not ;)  No one else is requesting you elaborate, so maybe it is just me, or maybe it is a case of *emperors new clothes*.  All I asked was that you enumerate the equivalents, not necessarily explain them.

Answer (score 2):

A function pointer is used in any situation where the function to be called is determined at runtime rather than compile-time.  This includes callbacks, but may also be used as a switch-case alternative for example, and to adapt the behaviour of a function by passing a function pointer that defines that behaviour - this is how the standard library `qsort()` function works for example, enabling it to sort any kind of object.

I have used them in particular to implement a command line parser that evaluates C expressions entered as strings at run-time, and can include function calls.  This uses a *symbol table* to lookup the pointer to the function so it can be called on demand from the operator.

All you might ever wish to know on the subject can be found at [The Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)

In the end function pointers are just one of those rarely used tools you keep in your bag.  If you understand them, when the situation arises where it may provide a solution, you will hopefully recognise it.

Answer (score 2):

It is the only way you can implement [Higher Order Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) in C.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, I've found that one of the most significant uses of function pointers (other than for callbacks) is to enable the construction of generic data structures.

Say you want to construct a hashmap with arbitrary keys and values. One way to do that is declare both `void *key` and `void *value` and then pass in two function pointers during the initialization phase: `int (*hashcode)(void*)` and `int (*equals)(void*, void*)`.

This gives you the ability to build a hashmap that can take basically anything that you can write the above two functions for. In my case, the key was a fixed size character buffer and the value was a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 2):

It is also used in the following

- Making jump tables(like vector tables or **ISR**)
- making the function abstract
- Developing Finite State Machines (as state, action and triggered even can easily be implemented using the function pointers, the design also seems to be easy and more readable in that)
- Event Driven Framework(GUI - gtk is an example)

Answer (score 1):

Other than callbacks (great for abstraction), function pointers can be used to implement polymorphism in C. This is done extensively in the Linux kernel, and common C libraries such as glibc, GTK+ and GLib.